# Json Response needs to update Javascript value and replace global initial global value - work around solution needed

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api, jsonresponse, jsonencoder

I'm trying to wrap my head around the fetch api and get. From what i've been studying it looks like its suppose to be easy but my mind isn't getting it fully. In my game Javascript, it starts with a money=2000 global variable.

The game plays fine, but when someone leaves and goes to their profile page and comes back to the game, the game resets and starts the play from the beginning and resets the money back to 2000.

What is really crazy is if I refresh the page I finally see the correct value of 2200 on the web page, which is what is in the database.

startgame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
<TITLE>Interactive Game</TITLE>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body background="images/pvpcoinnew.png" style="width=120%" onLoad="updateMoney(); popup('popUpDiv'); click(); updown()" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<img background="images/pvpcoinnew.png">

<select id="textbox">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25" selected>25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="250">250</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select> 
    <button type="click" id="button" onclick="enterWager(); return false;">Wager!</button>

    <p>Money: $<span id="money"></span><br></p>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The game.js file below has money preset at the very beginning to 2000.
game.js

```
//money = 2000;
window.money = 2000;
          
fetch('../php/moneyupdate/moneyupdate.php?money=value')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((money) => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    window.money = money
    console.log(money)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Do something for an error here
  })
  
  
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = window.money;
```

When the php file is triggered from the fetch the status is 200. XHR Response Payload comes back with "2200" which is what is in the database, but the web page is still showing 2000.

Here is the moneyupdate.php file

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    header("Location: ../login/index.php");
}
include('../../login/database.php');


if(isset($_GET["money"])) {
  $money = htmlspecialchars($_GET["money"]);
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

try {
$db = DB();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT money FROM usersystem WHERE userid=?");
$stmt->execute([$userid]);
$money = $stmt->fetchColumn();


// send a JSON encded money array to client
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($money);
//}


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $db = null;  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
}
// Notes: The json_encode function returns the JSON representation of the given value. 
//        The json_decode takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
?>
```

Thanks for the help and responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using GET['money'] add this to your url "http:site.com/page.php?money=value".
window.money = 2000;

```
fetch('../php/moneyupdate/moneyupdate.php?money=2000')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((money) => {
    // Work with JSON data here
     //working with json data depends on structure 
      // you can access data as money.money
    window.money = money
    console.log(money)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Do something for an error here
  })
```

Comment: Okay this helped a little. I finally have "2200" in my network, XHR, response. But the page still shows 2000. I need to research the windows.money answer, I don't think I have what he suggested correct. Thank you so far !!!

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly, you might want to use the object window to store your variable and you can access it from anywhere

```
    window.money = 2000;
    
    fetch('../php/moneyupdate/moneyupdate.php')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((money) => {
        // Work with JSON data here
        window.money = money
        console.log(money)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Do something for an error here
      })
```

About the PHP part, I wish I could help but that is not my strength. I hope my tip helped you though.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. the database is showing, as well as the profile page 2200 money, but the game still shows 2000 when I go back to it from the profile page. I will however look more into window, and the response payload is still showing var money = null;

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, this line should also use the window.money variable: document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
Did you change it as well?

Comment: If I understand you correctly are you saying to change my global to window.money = 2000; ?

Comment: Okay I changed the global as you suggested. It sort of works now.

Comment: I am now thinking it might be my onLoad="updateMoney()

Comment: would it be possible to make window.money = fetch string?

Answer (score 0):

Solved -
At first I wasn't sure where to put the getElementById, not realizing it needed to be within fetch. I also put the fetch into a function so it could be called from html file onload, which I show on html page file. I also inserted it within the updateMoney(). It instantly solved my issue of having to reload the page to see the money value displayed.

game.js

```
 // window.money = 2000;
    function getMoney(){
    fetch('../php/moneyupdate/moneyupdate.php?money=value')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((money) => {
        // Work with JSON data here
        window.money = money
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = window.money;
        //console.log(money)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Do something for an error here
      })
    }

function updateMoney() {
       if ( pot <= 0 ){ 
       if ( money <= 0 ){ 
       document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML = "Lost? Here's A Loan !!!";
          money = 1000 ;}
      }
//       document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
         document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = window.money;
      }
```

Having the code above in JS wasn't all I needed to do. I had to actually trigger the getMoney() so it would fetch the php file and get the column from the database.

startgame.html

```
<body background="images/pvpcoinnew.png" style="width=120%" onLoad="getMoney(); updateMoney(); popup('popUpDiv'); click(); updown()" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

I didn't need to change anything on the php page, but im still wondering if I really needed this line since i'm not using it for anything. $money = htmlspecialchars($_GET["money"]);

moneyupdate.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    header("Location: ../login/index.php");
}
include('../../login/database.php');


if(isset($_GET["money"])) {
  $money = htmlspecialchars($_GET["money"]);
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

try {
$db = DB();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT money FROM usersystem WHERE userid=?");
$stmt->execute([$userid]);
$money = $stmt->fetchColumn();


// send a JSON encded money array to client
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($money);
//}


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $db = null;  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
}
// Notes: The json_encode function returns the JSON representation of the given value. 
//        The json_decode takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
?>
```